# not able to retrieve data from web table of the site https://demoqa.com/webtables

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-ide

not able to retrieve data from web table of the site https://demoqa.com/webtables

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "E:\\geckodriver.exe");
    WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
    driver.get("https://demoqa.com/webtables");
    
    
    List <WebElement> col = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*[@class='rt-resizable-header-content']/tbody/tr"));
    System.out.println(col.size());
    

}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Do you get any errors? Without additional information it is difficult for us to help you with your question.